# Python _thread is not executing?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a chat client which interacts with my server. In order to do this, I am using a thread from the _thread module to allowing sending and receiving to run simultaneously. However, when I launch the program, I am getting nothing. No allowed received messages, and no prompt to send any either. What's wrong?

Code:

```
import socket
from _thread import *


host = 'localhost'
port = 9999
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host,port))






'''while True:
    sock.send(input('REPLY: ').encode('utf-8'))
    print(str(sock.recv(1000)))



'''
x = None






def sendMess(x):
    print('sendMess started')
    while True:
        x = input("SEND: ")
        sock.send(x.encode("utf-8"))
    return





def recvMess(x):
    print('recvMess started.')
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(4000)
        print(str(data))
    return                

if sock:

    start_new_thread(sendMess, (x,))

    start_new_thread(recvMess, (x,))
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you shouldn't use the `_thread` module anymore, use the higher level `threading` module.

The problem in your example is that after you start your threads, the main thread exits.

The [`_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html#index-2) documentation warns you about this:

> **Caveats**:
>
> [...]
>
> - When the main thread exits, it is system defined whether the other threads survive. On most systems, they are killed without executing try ... finally clauses or executing object destructors.

So that means that your threads are destroyed before they can really do any work. [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) objects behave differently here, they're not destroyed unless they have their `daemon` flag set.

To make it work, just change your code like this:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

...

if sock:
    Thread(target=sendMess, args=(x,)).start()
    Thread(target=recvMess, args=(x,)).start()
```